# Is this the correct way to overload the left-stream operator? (C++)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stream, ostream

This function declaration gives me errors:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, hand& obj);
```

The errors are:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
error C4430: missing type specifier
error C2065: 'os' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'obj' : undeclared identifier
error C2275: 'hand' : illegal use of this type as an expression
    see declaration of 'hand'
error C4430: missing type specifier
```

hand is a class I made, display is a public data member of type `char*`.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The declaration looks right. But the error message suggests that `ostream` is not known as a type. Try including the `iostream` header and say `std::ostream` instead.

Another thing you should consider is making the parameter 'hand' a const reference. So you could also accept temporaries and print them out.

Answer (score 2):

is this inside a header?  then you probably need to say `std::ostream`.  Make sure you `#include<iosfwd>`.

Also, you can probably say `const hand&`.